# reactjs redux "Cannot read property 'isFetching' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, redux

i create new redux store and action but it show error

> Cannot read property `isFetching` of undefined

My code is:

**store.js**

```
import * as ActionTypes from '../actions/secone'

const productBrand = (state={records:[], isFetching: false}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.PRODUCT_BRAND_REQUEST:
        return { ...state, isFetching: true}
    case ActionTypes.PRODUCT_BRAND_SUCCESS:
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
export default productBrand
```

**action.js**

```
import { CALL_API } from '../middlewares/api'

export const PRODUCT_BRAND_REQUEST = 'PRODUCT_BRAND_REQUEST'
export const PRODUCT_BRAND_SUCCESS = 'PRODUCT_BRAND_SUCCESS'
export const PRODUCT_BRAND_FAILURE = 'PRODUCT_BRAND_FAILURE'

export const fetchProductBrand = () => (dispatch, getState) =>  {
    if (!getState().productBrand.isFetching) {
        dispatch({
            [CALL_API]: {
                types: [ PRODUCT_BRAND_REQUEST,PRODUCT_BRAND_SUCCESS,PRODUCT_BRAND_FAILURE ],
            endpoint: 'productbrand'
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**component.js**

```
class SecOne extends Component {

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchProductBrand()
}

handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.refs.brand.refs.searchTextField.input.value)
};

render() {

    const data = [];
    // const {productBrand} = this.props

    return (
        <div>
           <Tabs>
                <Tab icon={<Bike />} label="Motor" >
                    <div style={style.secOneField}>
                        <AutoComplete id="brand" ref="brand" floatingLabelText="Brand" dataSource={data} maxSearchResults={5} filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter} openOnFocus={true}/>
                        <RaisedButton label="Search" primary={true} onClick={this.handleOnSubmit}/>
                    </div>
                </Tab>
                <Tab icon={<Car />} label="Mobil">
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </Tab>
            </Tabs>
        </div>
    );
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
     productBrand: state.productBrand.records
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    fetchProductBrand: () => dispatch(fetchProductBrand())
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(SecOne);
```

i don't know why the state is not detected?
productBrand: state.productBrand.records
this state is not detected (defined)
is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you show code where you create store? Your `store.js` is actually a file with reducers code.

Comment: That's because you're using reducer, and you can access your reducer state using `state.REDUCER_NAME.property`, so in this case you can access the state of your `productBrand` reducer by doing (in mapStateToProps) `productBrand: state.productBrand` and then in your components you can call `props.productBrand.records` and `props.productBrand.isFetching` to access the state.

Comment: thank you guys i solve the issue
i import the wrong name in reducers combine
   
import productBrand from './secone' ## THIS IS THE ISSUE I PUT the variable "secone" instead of the name of the store in this case which is productBrand
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'

// Updates error message to notify about the failed fetches.


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    productBrand,
    routing: routerReducer
})

export default rootReducer
THANK YOU VERY MUCH GUYS
anyway sorry for the ugly format in this comment, i am still new in stackoverflow